# What is the most light-weight method to store a string in an property of type TObject?

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe2, boxing

The situation:

I create visual components from a `TDataSet` that should keep an id as a reference. The component can only store objects, not strings.

Pseudo code:

```
for Record in DataSet do
  AddComponent.Data := Record['id']
```

Where `Data` is of type `TObject` and the `id` field is of a string type (actually a GUID).

The question:

How do I store a string in the object property?

I have tried a boxing solution that uses a custom type `TBox<string>`, but I want to avoid memory management issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type of `Data` is `TObject` then you cannot avoid memory management issues. The compiler is not going to manage the lifetime of a `TObject` instance for you. You will have to use one of the standard lifetime management mechanisms:

1. You take care of it with try/finally blocks, and explicit calls to `Free`.
2. You derive your object from `TComponent` and let it be owned by something that is guaranteed to outlive all references to your wrapped string.

Option 2 has a number of variants. Other ways to hand off ownership include using interfaces. So long as the owner outlives all references to the object then you are safe.

Personally I don't very much like option 2. If the compiler isn't going to manage the lifetime of my objects, I prefer to manage it myself. I find that if I use explicit management then it is easier to reason about when my objects' lives end.

Comment: Might I also suggest `TGUID` as an appropriate object, via `StringToGUID`, into which to store the GUID contained in `Record`.  It would provide a sanity check for the GUID at the same time, which is probably a good thing.

Comment: I wish Delphi had reference counting for objects *sigh*.

Comment: @J... The database already ensures that the strings are valid GUIDs.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff The next gen compiler will support automatic reference counting for objects.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's very nice, I'm looking forward for the next gen compiler then :)

Comment: ...which would probably open a new can of worms like random freeing of exclusive resources.

Comment: @Arioch'The Why? ARC is a well proven solution to the problem.

Comment: @David We'll see. If they just wanted to make TObject clones of TInterfacedObject - they could just re-write RTL/VCL/FMX to use it as its base. New TObject should compile old Create/Destroy based code as well as ARC-based one with the same TObject Sources. We'll see how EMBA would manage to do. But at least that would remove one of the tools from stock toolbox. Adding TIO was giving flexibility, removing them would be limiting it.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I store a string in the object property?

Why ?

Well,

1. `sizeof(TObject) = sizeof(Pointer)`
2. `String` is ref-counted type, so you'd either use `StringRec` cracker type and manage all the intrinsics, or use the compielr build-in counter. I'd try th second approach, despite it being less effectve and adding extra indirection level.

.

```
type StringContainer = record Data: String; end;
     PStringContainer = ^StringContainer;

var p: PStringContainer;

for Record in DataSet do begin
  New(P);
  P^.Data := Record['id'];
  Pointer(AddComponent.Data) := P;
end;
```

Don't forget to call `Dispose(...)` when you'll no more need those pointers in the component.

```
procedure TMyComponent.BeforeDestruction;
var P: PStringContainer;
begin
    P := Pointer(Data);
    Data := nil;
    Dispose(P); // should free the string, since P type was given
    inherited; 
end;
```

> I want to avoid memory management issues.

Which kind of issues exactly and  in which part of the program ?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's going to be less complex than `TBox<string>`. Which presumably is `TBox<T> = class FValue: T; end;`

Comment: By `memory management issues` I meant things like double free or leaks, strings are managed by the compiler, but objects are not. I thought that there was some trick, but I guess David is right.

Comment: @David that depends upon interpretation of "complex" and "light-weight" `New/Dispose` certainly are more lightweight than deep nested calls of objects creations/destroying.

Comment: @Arioch'The `TObject.NewInstance` isn't that much more heavy than `New`. Also, I see `DataSet` here, so let's see the bigger picture.

Comment: NewInstance is only one of the sequence of calls, really. Though in general you're correct of larger picture...

Comment: @Arioch'The `NewInstance` is the only one that does any work in `TBox<T>`. It does the heap alloc and then populates the VMT. That VMT population is the only part of object construction that takes more time than the code in your answer.

Comment: @David `.Create` is called, even if it is empty stub. Ditto for `.AfterConstruction`, ditto for special compiler stub to assure constructor called by specific convention (DL register et all). Same goes for destruction: `.Free/.Destroy/.BeforeDestruction` It is copmmon place that before advanced records matured (for example in D2006 they are not practically usable) for hi-perf code old TP-style objects were used. And advanced records perhaps was partially introduced to provide means to replace TP-style objects, when discarding them in proposed LLVM-Delphi-Gen2

Comment: Surely those call chains are very flexible and for usual objects their impact is bearable or even non-significant. But when the object is merely boxing this overload becomes very large share of allocation/deallocation sequence, and the better MM is, the larger the share is.

Comment: What happened when you did the timing comparison?

Comment: By light-weight I meant "with the least LOC", sorry for the confusion. I prefer readable code over marginally faster code in this case. It's only for a few records.